# sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert request contains invalid data

Tags: salesforce

Having some trouble using the bulk:upsert command to update Account objects via a csv file.  Hopefully someone can help me with this.  Below is what I'm doing:

My csv file name is account.csv and it contains the following data:

```
Id,Name
0012F00000QjhC7QAJ,LimTest 1
0012F00000QjhkSQAR,LimTest 2
```

Below is the command that I'm running:

```
sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -s Account -f account.csv -i Id -u dev
```

Above command gets submitted sucessfully.  But the job failed. 
 The Batch status is as of below:
[image: Batch Status]

When I view the request, it looks like below:
[image: Request]

Answer (score 0):

It works after I manually created an empty file and copied and pasted the data into this new file.  The original file, account.csv, was created using this command: 
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "select Id, Name from Account" -r csv -u dev > account.csv

I guess the above command must have created the file in a different encoding that the bulk:upsert does not know how to handle.